# How to correct this error : The following object is masked from ‘package:caret’:

Tags: r, regression, feature-selection

In R, when I try to use the package fscaret I am getting an issue with RMSE.

```
library("fscaret")
Loading required package: caret
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: ggplot2
Note: the specification for S3 class “family” in package ‘MatrixModels’ seems equivalent to one from package ‘lme4’: not turning on duplicate class definitions for this class.
Loading required package: gsubfn
Loading required package: proto
Loading required package: hmeasure
Loading required package: parallel

Attaching package: ‘fscaret’

The following object is masked from ‘package:caret’:

    RMSE
```

This resulted in error while calculating RMSE values for a regrression problem.

What could be done to get  this issue corrected.
Any suggestions or advice?

Comment: You can use `caret::RMSE` instead of `RMSE`. The message is telling you that RMSE is now coming from `fscaret` rather than `caret`.

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning.